# Parse list only one time instead of many

Tags: python, list-manipulation

I have this function that parse 4 times the same list :

```
def function (a_list):
      A = sum([i[1] + i[2] for i in a_list]) 
      B = sum([(i[1] + i[2])*i[3] for i in a_list]) 
      C = sum([i[3] for i in a_list])
      D = list(set([i[0] for i in a_list]))
      return A+B+C+D
```

Could I do it easily parsing only one time? Thanks!

SL

Comment: `A+B+C+D` makes no sense. The first 3 are numbers, the last is a list. You can't add a list to a number.

Comment: Can you give an example of `a_list` ?

Comment: You don't need a list comprehension when calling `sum()`. It will work with the generator directly.

Comment: If you're asking if you can avoid looping through the list each time, I don't think so. You're doing a different calculation each time, and I don't think there's anything you can cache between each of these to avoid looping again.

Comment: a_list_example = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]] ; Could I start with the for like this :
def function (a_list): for i in a_list ... and do the operations one by one below?

Comment: @Barmar sorry for the return... My function is a lot longer and I wrote this quickly.. I just need to focus on the loops.